# How to return object value based on array value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How can I return object value based on array value in JavaScript.

Array Object:

```
const options = [
  { value: 'a', label: 'Apple' },
  { value: 'b', label: 'Boy' },
  { value: 'd', label: 'Boy' },
];
```

Array:

```
const status = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Output expectation:

```
result = ['Apple', 'Boy']
```

I tried as below but it gives me a whole object in return

```
options.filter(option => status.includes(option.value))
```

Comment: Yes. you almost finish it. you only need to add ```.map(el=>el.label)```  after ```filter()``` to return the result.

Comment: `options.filter(option => status.includes(option.value)).map(item => (item.label))`